# Boot time takes more than 5 minutes after moving partitions in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, systemd

I screwed somehow my Ubuntu after deleting my Windows 10 partition and moving my ubuntu 18.04 into it; then using the old Ubuntu partition to set there /home using Gparted and following this [instructions](https://www.maketecheasier.com/move-home-folder-ubuntu/). After that, I've been suffering a very slow boot (before the moving was under 15 seconds). This is the result of systemd-analyze blame:

```
    4min 48.912s plymouth-quit-wait.service
    3min 16.461s snapd.seeded.service
         30.037s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
         15.208s snapd.service
          3.368s esets.service
           961ms fwupd.service
```

and this is systemd-analyze critical-chain

```
graphical.target @4min 51.235s
└─multi-user.target @4min 51.235s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @1min 31.439s +3min 16.461s
    └─snapd.service @4min 32.688s +15.208s
      └─basic.target @1.249s
        └─sockets.target @1.249s
          └─snapd.socket @1.238s +10ms
            └─sysinit.target @1.208s
              └─apparmor.service @905ms +302ms
                └─local-fs.target @903ms
                  └─run-user-121.mount @2.548s
                    └─swap.target @830ms
                      └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-8c6b3935\x2deca8\x2d40b7\x2db2c0\x2dba0d06a9deaf.swap @814ms +15ms
                        └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-8c6b3935\x2deca8\x2d40b7\x2db2c0\x2dba0d06a9deaf.device @805ms
```

The system takes more than five minutes to start. Many solutions point out to the swap having a wrong UUID, but I checked it out and it is correct. This is my /etc/fstab

```
# / was on /dev/sda during installation
UUID=6c2a22c4-02c7-485f-9127-5913015612e4 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# home
UUID=453a1115-0384-455b-b0dd-6e76020b7ffa /home           ext4    defaults 0       2
# /windows/c was on /dev/sda1 during installation
# UUID=0E9AFC419AFC26BD /windows/c      ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
# /windows/d was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=2080AA3F80AA1B74   /windows/d  ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46   0   0
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=8c6b3935-eca8-40b7-b2c0-ba0d06a9deaf none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I get some (hopefully relevant) parts of the output of journalctl -b

```
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc kernel: shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Configuration File System.
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd-udevd[325]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Started Apply Kernel Variables.
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042F conflicts with OpRegion 0x00000000000
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc kernel: ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x00000000000
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc kernel: ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x00000000000
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc kernel: ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x00000000000
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc kernel: ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc kernel: lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
```

This is another (hopefully) relevant chunk

```
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Found device OCZ-VERTEX3 6.
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Found device OCZ-VERTEX3 Home.
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Found device OCZ-VERTEX3 DATA.
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Mounting /windows/d...
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/453a1115-0384-455b-b0dd-6e76020b7ffa...
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Activating swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/8c6b3935-eca8-40b7-b2c0-ba0d06a9deaf...
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc kernel: Adding 16777044k swap on /dev/sda6.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:16777044k SSFS
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Activated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/8c6b3935-eca8-40b7-b2c0-ba0d06a9deaf.
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd-fsck[623]: Home: clean, 525962/9052160 files, 27873082/36190918 blocks
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Started File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/453a1115-0384-455b-b0dd-6e76020b7ffa.
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Mounting /home...
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Mounted /windows/d.
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc ntfs-3g[632]: Version 2017.3.23 integrated FUSE 28
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc ntfs-3g[632]: Mounted /dev/sda5 (Read-Write, label "DATA", NTFS 3.1)
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc ntfs-3g[632]: Cmdline options: rw,umask=007,gid=46
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc ntfs-3g[632]: Mount options: rw,allow_other,nonempty,relatime,default_permissions,fsname=/dev/sda5,blkdev,blksiz
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc ntfs-3g[632]: Global ownership and permissions enforced, configuration type 7
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc ntfs-3g[632]: Warning : using problematic uid==0 and gid!=0
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Mounted /home.
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems.
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc kernel: EXT4-fs (sda7): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Starting AppArmor initialization...
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Starting Set console font and keymap...
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Starting Clean up any mess left by 0dns-up...
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
Jul 06 12:46:43 development-pc systemd[1]: Starting Enable support for additional executable binary formats...
```

This is the first critical error, but does not seem to be related with the delay culprits.

```
Jul 06 12:46:45 development-pc dbus-daemon[997]: [session uid=121 pid=997] Activating service name='org.gnome.ScreenSaver' requested by ':1.12'
Jul 06 12:46:45 development-pc org.gnome.ScreenSaver[997]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jul 06 12:46:45 development-pc gnome-screensav[1014]: Cannot open display: 
Jul 06 12:46:45 development-pc dbus-daemon[997]: [session uid=121 pid=997] Activated service 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver' failed: Process org.gnome.
Jul 06 12:46:45 development-pc gnome-session[999]: gnome-session-binary[999]: CRITICAL: Unable to create a DBus proxy for GnomeScreensaver: Err
Jul 06 12:46:45 development-pc gnome-session-binary[999]: CRITICAL: Unable to create a DBus proxy for GnomeScreensaver: Error calling StartServ
Jul 06 12:46:45 development-pc kernel: nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (65536 buckets, 262144 max)
Jul 06 12:46:46 development-pc kernel: bridge: filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default. Update your scripts to load br
Jul 06 12:46:46 development-pc kernel: Netfilter messages via NETLINK v0.30.
Jul 06 12:46:46 development-pc kernel: ip_set: protocol 6
```

This part has several errors

```
Jul 06 12:46:47 development-pc kernel: virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered disabled state
Jul 06 12:46:47 development-pc avahi-daemon[769]: wide-area.c: Failed to send packet.
Jul 06 12:46:47 development-pc colord-sane[844]: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
Jul 06 12:46:48 development-pc kernel: e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
Jul 06 12:46:48 development-pc kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s25: link becomes ready
Jul 06 12:46:48 development-pc systemd[1]: Started ESET NOD32 Antivirus.
Jul 06 12:46:48 development-pc esets_mac[1268]: error[04f40000]: IDUS_ERROR_CANNOT_UNBLOCK_REMOVABLE_MEDIA|Cannot unblock removable media (org.
Jul 06 12:46:49 development-pc set-cpufreq[772]: Setting powersave scheduler for all CPUs
Jul 06 12:47:03 development-pc esets_mac[1306]: error[051a0000]: IDUS_ERROR_CANNOT_UNBLOCK_REMOVABLE_MEDIA|Cannot unblock removable media (org.
Jul 06 12:47:15 development-pc systemd[1]: NetworkManager-wait-online.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 06 12:47:15 development-pc systemd[1]: NetworkManager-wait-online.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 06 12:47:15 development-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager Wait Online.
Jul 06 12:47:15 development-pc systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
Jul 06 12:47:15 development-pc systemd[1]: Starting Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures...
```

The snap daemon fails to start three times before it made it (look for the timestamp jumps all posted here is consecutive in the log).

```
Jul 06 12:47:15 development-pc audit[729]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=729 comm="cupsd" family="uni
Jul 06 12:47:15 development-pc kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 18 callbacks suppressed
Jul 06 12:47:15 development-pc kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1530906435.478:29): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="/usr/sbin/cups
Jul 06 12:48:08 development-pc esets_mac[1434]: error[059a0000]: IDUS_ERROR_CANNOT_UNBLOCK_REMOVABLE_MEDIA|Cannot unblock removable media (org.
Jul 06 12:48:14 development-pc systemd[1]: snapd.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul 06 12:48:14 development-pc systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul 06 12:48:14 development-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Snappy daemon.
Jul 06 12:48:14 development-pc systemd[1]: Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
Jul 06 12:48:14 development-pc systemd[1]: snapd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 06 12:48:14 development-pc systemd[1]: snapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Jul 06 12:48:14 development-pc systemd[1]: Stopped Snappy daemon.
Jul 06 12:48:14 development-pc systemd[1]: Starting Snappy daemon...
Jul 06 12:49:38 development-pc esets_daemon[1432]: error[05980000]: Error updating Antivirus modules: An error occurred while downloading updat
Jul 06 12:49:44 development-pc systemd[1]: snapd.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul 06 12:49:44 development-pc systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul 06 12:49:44 development-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Snappy daemon.
Jul 06 12:49:44 development-pc systemd[1]: snapd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 06 12:49:44 development-pc systemd[1]: snapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Jul 06 12:49:44 development-pc systemd[1]: Stopped Snappy daemon.
Jul 06 12:49:44 development-pc systemd[1]: Starting Snappy daemon...
Jul 06 12:51:15 development-pc systemd[1]: snapd.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul 06 12:51:15 development-pc systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul 06 12:51:15 development-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Snappy daemon.
Jul 06 12:51:15 development-pc systemd[1]: snapd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 06 12:51:15 development-pc systemd[1]: snapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Jul 06 12:51:15 development-pc systemd[1]: Stopped Snappy daemon.
Jul 06 12:51:15 development-pc systemd[1]: Starting Snappy daemon...
J
```

I follow many articles in Internet and here, but there is not any that shows what configuration file has to be adjusted in order to align the service to the correct partition UUID. Some pointed to the journal to change to journal.org, but it didn't work.

Has someone a better idea I ran out of them to solve this issue which is present in two Ubuntu machines now. Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks to me like snapdaemon is taking more time. See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snapd-service-delays-startup-in-ubuntu-18-04-with-4-15-0-24/6205 and bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1780062

Comment: Did you try booting with kernel 4.15.0-23?  That apparently does not have the entropy problem.